How do I unschedule a video?
I scheduled a video on my channel to be publicly watchable on a certain date. How do I cancel the schedule and leave the video as private? I see options to change when the video goes public, but no way to cancel making it public altogether.


Visibility Settings
YouTube's interface does not make it clear but the options in Save or Publish and Schedule are mutually exclusive and only the most recently saved visibility settings are applied to the video.
Saving new settings will overwrite the previous ones.
Switch Video from 'Scheduled' to 'Private'

Open the Visibility settings for a scheduled video
 For example, hover over the current setting and click the arrow that appears


To expand the Save or Publish section, click the down arrow


Private will already be selected, so click Save


The video's visibility will now be Private instead of Scheduled


To schedule the video again, open the video's Visibility settings, and click the down arrow to expand the Schedule section


Configure the date and time, then click Schedule


The video's visibility will now be Scheduled instead of Private



